# Failed to update point geometry through WFS-T request when sending it with python

Tags: python, geoserver, wfs-t

I am trying to update some data on postgis through a WFS request to geoserver.
More specifically I want to update the geometry of a point.
My XML looks like this **and works correctly when I execute it through geoserver Demos section**:

```
        <wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.1.0"
          xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
          xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
          xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml">
          <wfs:Update typeName="geonode:idn_poi_tradecenter_sumba_rbi25k_big_a">
            <wfs:Property>
              <wfs:Name>the_geom</wfs:Name>
              <wfs:Value>
                  <gml:Point>
                    <gml:pos>-9.37861241467984 120.9814453125</gml:pos>
                 </gml:Point>
                </wfs:Value>
            </wfs:Property>
            <ogc:Filter>
              <ogc:FeatureId fid='idn_poi_tradecenter_sumba_rbi25k_big_a.11'/>
            </ogc:Filter>
          </wfs:Update>
        </wfs:Transaction>​
```

When I execute exactly the same xml using python requests, the point is not updated. Although I do get a status_code = 200 back when I print the response of the request I get this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wfs:TransactionResponse xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:geonode="http://www.geonode.org/" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd">
<wfs:TransactionSummary><wfs:totalInserted>0</wfs:totalInserted>
<wfs:totalUpdated>1</wfs:totalUpdated>
<wfs:totalDeleted>0</wfs:totalDeleted></wfs:TransactionSummary>
<wfs:TransactionResults/>
<wfs:InsertResults>
<wfs:Feature>
<ogc:FeatureId fid="none"/>
</wfs:Feature>
</wfs:InsertResults>
</wfs:TransactionResponse>
```

If you notice in the response its mentioned:

```
<ogc:FeatureId fid="none"/>
```

Does anyone has an idea what's going on?

**EDIT**

I found out what was the problem. It was related with encoding issues and hidden whitespaces or something like this.
The issue (and major mistake) was that I have copied my XML structure to my email and then I took it from there. Sometimes this cause trouble such as adding hidden spaces etc.

I had to retype the XML string and then it worked.
What made me suspect this issue was this line in geoserver log:

```
Content is not allowed in trailing section
```

Comment: can you add the python code you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you set the "Content-type" header of your request to "application/xml" or "text/xml"?

Comment: Yes. I set it as: headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}

Comment: In my geoserver log I get: columnNumber: 31; Content is not allowed in trailing section. Which I dont understand. I have checked the XML in an online validator and its valid.

Comment: Seems like whatever geoserver is getting is not valid anymore. Maybe there are character encoding issues?